# How can i tell the program to add a new field to an object?

Tags: java, object, field

So i have this mini project im doing, and it basically requires the program to read from a text file and add the info to the object. However, i want the program to add a new field if it finds a new field that isnt available programatically.

```
public class Person{
    public person(String name, int age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }  
}
```

Lets say this is my object for now, and the information for my input from the text file is like:
Name=John Age=21 lastName=Doe. (But each one will be a line of its own)
And this would be my main:

```
public class miniProject{
    ArrayList<String> fields= new ArrayList<String> ();
    ArrayList<String> data= new ArrayList<String> ();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNOtFoundException{
        Person temp;
        File file = new File("personInfo.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String[] info=in.nextLine().split("="); //assuming ill get ["Name","John"] for the first line
            fields.add(info[0]);
            data.add(info[1]);
        }
        for (x=0;x<field.length;x++){
            if (person.field[x]==null){ //im not really sure how id check for this
               //make new field and add info
            }else{
                person.field[x]=data[x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

im sorry if this is really wonky, i havent had the time to start it so i just coded this right now. When making the new field should it be in the object class that i call upon? for example:

```
public class Person{
    public person(String name, String age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
    public void newField(String field, String info){
        this.field=info;
    }
}
```

and then i can call on that?

Comment: I would suggest you to keep each line specific to the property of one individual and separated by a delimiter. Thus reading and processing it would be much easier.

Comment: You can use a `Map<String. String>` to be able to add any field/value as needed. This is easy to iterate the values. Where this become problematic is with the type of data.

Comment: Im alternating between using that and using an arrayList of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that and having some flexibility would be using something called PropertiesBag.  It is a [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object that you will be able to add new keys and assign values to them. You can have it as a member of your `Person` class in the question. Then you will need to implement getter and setter for the property, similarly to the `Properties` class.
So, if you are OK with your properties being of a very simple types (String or anything that can be instantiated from String) you should be fine.

[Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/properties/java-util-properties-example/) you could find some example of working with Properties

Comment: that sounds like the most probable choice, how would i use the properties object for this instance if you dont mind me asking

Comment: Do not expode the Properties object itself, instead create getProperty and setProperty method in your Person class and call them when needed in your main.

Comment: I was thinking.. what if i create an arrayList of objects that contain a title (field) and info (just the info related), and store that into Person object? I know it will be more complicated, but wouldnt that be a possibility? And ill have a method in the Person object that would take a string argument as a title( for ex. name)  and search the arraylist by title and return the wanted object. And another one to add a new object to the arrayList.

Comment: With Properties you get get/add/set/remove and many other methods out of the box. In ArrayList you will need to implement something to avoid dupplications while adding new properties. To me personally it’s hard to see the advantages of ArrayList over Properties in this particular case.

Comment: Great, ill use that and see what i can do then. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can't have it both ways: Java is a statically compiled language. And **fields** of classes are a "static" thing. You can't add a *new* field programmatically at **runtime**. You can use reflection to figure dynamically what fields exist, and populate field content. That is what all the XML/JSON mappers do for you: read XML/JSON content and push values into Java object instances, or the other way round: fetch data from there, and turn it into XML/JSON files.

So, if you intend to use real fields, then there is no "adding things later". You have to design upfront what fields should be there. So, worst case, you define all potential options, and allow for many fields to be null/empty. Which is a bad idea, since it makes dealing with the corresponding objects really error prone.

Alternatively, if "dynamic" addressing via a **name** is your most important requirement, then simply change to use one field, that happens to be a Map, like:

```
Map<String, Object> myData = new HashMap<>();
```

But of course, that takes away all the advantages that using fields from "compile time" provide. As the other answer implies, *one* way of using such maps is by using aspects of standard Java [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) support.